# C++ Storing a class pointer in an abstract base class that can be accessed from derived classes?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, derived-class

I would like to store a pointer to the main Game class in my abstract Entity class.

Entity.h

```
#include "Game.h"

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity(Game* game);
    ~Entity(void);

    virtual void Draw(float dt) = 0;
    virtual void Update(float dt) = 0;          // '= 0' means pure virtual function (like 'abstract' in C#)

protected:
    Game* m_game;                               // Missing type specifier error C4430
};
```

Entity.cpp

```
#include "Entity.h"

Entity::Entity(Game* game)
{
    m_game = game;
}

Entity::~Entity(void)
{

}
```

I should then be able to instantiate a derived class and pass the Game class reference into the constructor so that it is passed to the base class where it is stored:

Boundary.h

```
#include "Entity.h"

class Boundary : public Entity
{
public:
    Boundary(Game* game);
    ~Boundary(void);

    // Override pure virtual functions
    void Draw(float dt);
    void Update(float dt);
};
```

The Boundary constructor can then use the referenced Game class in order to add itself to a list:

```
#include "Boundary.h"

Boundary::Boundary(Game* game) : Entity(game)
{
    // Add entity to the main entity list
    game->m_entities->push_back(*this);
}

Boundary::~Boundary(void)
{
}

void Boundary::Draw(float dt)
{
    // Call the base class as follows (C# equivalent: 'base.Draw(dt)')
    //Entity::Draw(dt);
}

void Boundary::Update(float dt)
{

}
```

This causes 3 kinds of problems:

`game->m_entities->push_back(*this);`

> error C2663: 'std::list<_Ty,_Ax>::push_back' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer

`Game* m_game;` in Entity.h

> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed

`list<Entity>* m_entities;` in Game.h

> error C2065: 'Entity' : undeclared identifier

`Entity(Game* game);` in Entity.h

> error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Game'

The C# equivalent of what I am trying to achieve is:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    protected Game game;

    public abstract void Draw(float dt);
    public abstract void Update(float dt);
}

public class Boundary : Entity
{
    public Boundary(Game game)
    {
        this.game = game;

        game.Entities.Add(this);
    }

    public override void Draw(float dt)
    {

    }

    public override void Update(float dt)
    {

    }
}
```

Where have I gone wrong?

EDIT:

```
Game.h

#include "btBulletDynamicsCommon.h"
//#include "LinearMath\btQuaternion.h"
#include <list>

using namespace std;        // Required for list

class Entity;               // Forward declaration

class Game
{
public:
    list<Entity>* m_entities;

    Game(void);
    ~Game(void);

    void init();
    void draw(float dt);
    void loadContent();
    void update(float dt);

private:
    class btDefaultCollisionConfiguration* m_collisionConfiguration;
    class btCollisionDispatcher* m_dispatcher;
    class btDiscreteDynamicsWorld* m_dynamicsWorld;
    class btBroadphaseInterface* m_overlappingPairCache;
    class btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver* m_solver;

    void exitPhysics();
    void initPhysics();
};
```

EDIT 2:

The only problem I am left with now is trying to refer to game in the constructor:

```
    Boundary::Boundary(Game *game) 
    : Entity(game)                  // Initialise base
{
    // Add entity to the main entity list
    game->m_entities->push_back(*this);      // ERROR
}
```

The base class suffers from the same problem

```
    Entity::Entity(Game* game) 
    : m_game(game)                  // Initialise members
{
    m_game->m_entities->push_back(this);     // ERROR here too
}
```

Comment: When using Clang, if I make one change (define `m_entities` as `list<Entity*>` and use `game->m_entities->push_back(this)`) then it compiles just fine.

Comment: can you show us "Game.h" as well?

Comment: the call `m_entities->push_back(*this)` will not do what you want -- it will add a COPY of the current Boundary (and not a pointer to it) to `m_entities`; even if making this copy is possible, it would probably result in an infinite loop

Comment: you probably also need to forward-declare `class Entity` in Game.h before using it as a template argument to `list<>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### post-edit

This line in Game.h:

```
list<Entity>* m_entities;
```

declares a pointer to a list of Entity instances. Apart from the fact that you can't *use* this list until you've seen the definition of Entity (which isn't a problem here), it also means that any Entity you put into the list will be *copied*.  Since you're using subclasses of Entity, this will [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/212858) the object and only copy the base-class part.  So, your list is *not* polymorphic.  And, every time you create a Boundary (or whatever), it tries to add a *copy* of *only* its Entity base class subobject to the list.

Consider this instead:

```
list<Entity*> m_entities;
```

and maybe move the `push_back` to the base class too:

```
Entity::Entity(Game *game) : m_game(game)
{
    game->m_entities.push_back(this);
}

Boundary::Boundary(Game *game) : Entity(game) {}
```

(so you don't have to copy that for every subclass).

In general, when you want *runtime polymorphism* (derived classes and virtual functions) you need to use *indirection* such as pointers or references. Now that you're storing pointers, it's also a good idea to think about ownership and lifetime (storing smart pointers rather than raw pointers in that entity list might be a good start).

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<Entity> > m_entities;
```

Oh, and if you're deleting derived types via a base class indirection (like here), the base class destructor should be declared virtual as well.

---

### pre-edit

The *missing type specifier* error is your first clue: the compiler can't figure out what `Game` is when you refer to it in the definition of `Entity`.

Since you're including `Game.h`, either there's a problem with that header, or a circular dependency (ie, `Game.h` also includes `Entity.h`).

However, you don't need to include `Game.h` there at all:

### Entity.h

```
#ifndef USER1423893_ENTITY_H
#define USER1423893_ENTITY_H

class Game; // forward declaration

class Entity
{
public:
    virtual ~Entity(void);

    virtual void Draw(float dt) = 0;
    virtual void Update(float dt) = 0;

protected:
    explicit Entity(Game* game);

    Game* m_game;
};
#endif
```

### Entity.cpp

```
#include "Entity.h"

Entity::Entity(Game* game) : m_game(game)
{
}
```

What happens now you've fixed that error?

Comment: I get the following error for `game->m_entities->push_back(*this);` _pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed_

Comment: This line also produces _error C2027: use of undefined type 'Game'_ and _error C2259: 'Entity' : cannot instantiate abstract class_

Comment: After reading your answer more carefully and doing some further research I am left with one problem outlined by the second edit (EDIT 2).